# How to use add_theme_support('html5')?

Tags: theme-development, add-theme-support

I am trying to understand how `add_theme_support()` function works, but at the section of Html5 i tried to use it with gallery and i noticed that the markup has changed for it,and here is what i did

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array('gallery') );
```

but for the others like search-form or comment-form for example

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'comment-form','search-form','gallery', 'caption' ) );
```

i didn't notice any change in the output, so Am i missing some thing? or how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out why no changes happens, and the problem was that i am calling a custom search form file `searchform.php` and the function `add_theme_support()` affects the built in features only. So if you want to use the default search form by calling `get_search_form()` without having the `searchform.php` file, then you can use

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form' ) );
```

and this will apply an html5 markup to the form. The following are the before and after `add_theme_support()`(Contains  Arabic Text):

Before:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://localhost/TB/">
            <div>
                <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">البحث عن:</label>
                <input value="" name="s" id="s" type="text">
                <input id="searchsubmit" value="بحث" type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
```

After:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://localhost/TB/">
            <label>
                <span class="screen-reader-text">البحث عن:</span>
                <input class="search-field" placeholder="بحث …" value="" name="s" type="search">
            </label>
            <input class="search-submit" value="بحث" type="submit">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation, you must pass an array of items where you want to enable HTML5 markup:

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
    // Any or all of these.
    'comment-list', 
    'comment-form',
    'search-form',
    'gallery',
    'caption',
) );
```

The documentation also recommends using `add_theme_support()` on the `after_setup_theme` hook, stating that the `init` hook may be too late for some features.

### Reference

[Developer documentation: `add_theme_support()` » HTML5](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#html5)

Comment: sorry there is a miss understanding, i will edit my question

Comment: Since WordPress 5.3 `add_theme_support` allow more parameters: `style` and `script`,  to respectively remove `type="text/css"` and `type="text/javascript"` from links in enqueued scripts and styles. For example:`add_theme_support('html5', ['script', 'style']);`